# Bash: Get command output with variables inside the command

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, variables

i have a bash/shell script and want to store a command output in a variable (**EXCLUDE_PATTERN**) and the command itself contains also variables (**FOLDERS** and **BUPATH**).

the goal with this command is to replace the spaces in the variable **FOLDERS** with **" --exclude="$BUPATH** for use in an **tar** command

if have defined the following variables in the script:

```
FOLDERS='folder1 folder2 folder3'
BUPATH='/opt/mypath'
CONFIG_BACKUP="/storage/backup.tar.gz"
```

**FOLDER** is a variable with a list of excluded folders

**BUPATH** is a variable with a path

Now i want to define a variable **EXCLUDE_PATTERN** with the pattern for a following **tar** command (tried 2 variations):

```
EXCLUDE_PATTERN=`echo $FOLDERS | sed 's/\ /" --exclude="$BUPATH\//g'`
EXCLUDE_PATTERN=`echo $FOLDERS | sed 's/\ /" --exclude="${BUPATH}\//g'`
```

Then the script runs the tar command:

```
tar -C \"$BUPATH\" --exclude=\"$BUPATH/$EXCLUDE_PATTERN\" -czf \"$CONFIG_BACKUP\" .
```

It seems that the variable **EXCLUDE_PATTERN** is not recognizing the **BUPATH** variable:

```
tar -C "/opt/mypath" --exclude="/opt/mypath/folder1" --exclude="${BUPATH}/folder2" --exclude="${BUPATH}/folder3" -czf "/storage/config.tar.gz" .
```

The expected command should be this:

```
tar -C "/opt/mypath" --exclude="/opt/mypath/folder1" --exclude="/opt/mypath/folder2" --exclude="/opt/mypath/folder3" -czf "/storage/config.tar.gz" .
```

I hope someone can help me with this :)

Comment: Why did you escape those double quotes?

Comment: I have also tried without quotes, but it makes no difference (updated)

Comment: Why do you `\"` escape the `"`? Do you really have a directory named `"` ? Does `cd ./\"` work? Does `cd ./\"/opt/mypath` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> FOLDERS='folder1 folder2 folder3'
>
> BUPATH='/opt/mypath'
>
> CONFIG_BACKUP="/storage/backup.tar.gz"
>
> The expected command should be this:
>
> tar -C "/opt/mypath" --exclude="/opt/mypath/folder1" --exclude="/opt/mypath/folder2" --exclude="/opt/mypath/folder3" -czf "/storage/config.tar.gz" .

Well, that's simple. I like the `xargs printf` to transform a list, ex. prepend something:

```
# creates a bash array from newline separated output
IFS=$'\n' tarexcludes=($(<<<"$FOLDERS" xargs -n1 printf "--exclude=%s/%s\n" "$BUPATH"))
echo tar -C "/opt/mypath" "${tarexcludes[@]}" -czf "$CONFIG_BACKUP" .
```

But alternatively you could pick a unique sed command separator and:

```
tarexcludes=($(<<<"$FOLDERS" tr ' ' '\n' | sed "s~^~--exclude=$BUPATH/~"))
```

Or use `awk`:

```
tarexcludes=($(<<<"$FOLDERS" tr ' ' '\n' | awk -v BUPATH="$BUPATH" '{print "--exclude=" BUPATH "/" $0}')
```

Notes:

- Don't use backticks `. They are discouraged and I don't like them. [bash obsolete and deprecated syntax](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete)
- The `<<<"$FOLDERS"` is bash's [here string](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html)
- The `tr ' ' '\n'` substitutes spaces for newline. So it is parsable with sed.
- The `tarexcludes=( ... )` creates a bash array. [bashguide arrays](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays)
- You command does not work because `echo $FOLDERS` will output on a single line, and sed parses lines. So just replace spaces with newlines. Alternatively, use `xrandr -n1` or `printf "%s" $FOLDERS`
- By convention, upper case variable names are by convention reserved to environmentally exported variables. Use lowercase variable names in your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a combination of `"` `#` instead of `'` `/` as to solve your issue.

```sh
EXCLUDE_PATTERN=`echo $FOLDERS |  sed -e "s#\ #\" --exclude=$BUPATH\"/#g"`
```

but this will output:
`folder1" --exclude=/opt/mypath"/folder2" --exclude=/opt/mypath"/folder3`

To archive the expected output, it requires this modification:

```sh
EXCLUDE_PATTERN=`echo $FOLDERS |  sed -e "s#\(\S\+\)# --exclude=\"$BUPATH/\1\"#g"`
```

this will output:
`--exclude="/opt/mypath/folder1" --exclude="/opt/mypath/folder2" --exclude="/opt/mypath/folder3"`

For more information read the StackOverflow post:
[Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern)